# Oracle Stored Procedure not returning any value

Tags: c#, oracle, validation, authentication

I'm calling an oracle stored procedure from a c# login form but it's not returning any value. Thus `dt.rows.count` below is always 0 and the if part of the if-else statement is never executed, it always gets to the else part.

**C# code:**

```cs
String sConnectionString = "Data Source=XE;User ID=system;Password=system;";

OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(sConnectionString);
myConnection.Open();

OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand("spValidateDBA", myConnection);

myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.CommandText = "spValidateDBA";
myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
myCommand.Parameters["UserName"].Value = txtUsrId.Text.ToString();
myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserPassword", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
myCommand.Parameters["UserPassword"].Value = txtPassword.Text.ToString();
myCommand.Parameters.Add("DataCount", OracleDbType.Int32, 20).Direction =
ParameterDirection.Output;
OracleDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(myReader);


if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        CustomMsgbox.Show("\tLogin Successful\t" + Environment.NewLine +  
        "Welcome to DB Utilities Tool", "DB Utilities Tool", "OK", "Cancel");
        DBA dba = new DBA();
        dba.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

else
    CustomMsgbox.Show("Please enter correct Username/password",
    "DB Utilities Tool", "OK", "Cancel");
        myConnection.Close();
}
```

**Oracle stored procedure:**

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE spValidateDBA(
    UserName IN VARCHAR2,
    UserPassword IN VARCHAR2,
  DataCount OUT INTEGER)
  AS
BEGIN
select count(*) into DataCount from DBA_USER where USER_NAME=UserName and
    USER_PWD=UserPassword and USER_ROLE = 'DBA';
    END spValidateDBA;
```

Please note that table DBA_USER currently contains 1 row with values as:

```
USER_NAME   USER_PWD    USER_ROLE
   dask       password     DBA
```

Thus, `DataCount` in the above stored procedure should return 1 row with value as 1 when the inputs from the login form are dask(username) & password(userpassword), however it's not returning anything.

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong with this? I really need to get this issue resolved very soon.

Comment: OMG. Why do you create a table called DBA_USER when there's a system view called DBA_USERS? And why do you implement your own user validation logic when an Oracle session is perfectly capable of handling this? And why do you insist on creating your own `DBA` role instead of using the `predefined` DBA role? For anyone familiar with Oracle, this code is very, very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any result set from your SP so your datatable will be always empty. You are returning value in the output parameter. Use `ExecuteNonQuery` and then read value from parameter.

Try this

```
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
int dataCount = 0;
if(myCommand.Parameters["DataCount"] ! =null)
{
  dataCount = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.Parameters["DataCount"].Value);
}

if(dataCount > 0)
{
   CustomMsgbox.Show("...");
}
```